# WebMethod called with or without parameters

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, optional-parameters

what I'm trying to do is to set up a WCF Web-Service exposed through IIS that has one method called `GetArticle`. This method has to be called with a few obligatory parameters such as `userName` and `password` and with other optional parameters (for example, `brand`).

So the method signature looks like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public void GetArticle(string userName, string password, string brand)
```

The client that will consume the web-service makes calls to the method through query strings so I would receive:

```
http://localhost:5985/WebService?op=GetArticle&userName=ADMIN&password=ADMIN&brand=BRAND
```

And the method would return some data correctly. Since here no problems, but the client needs to have other data in return if it calls the method with ONLY the first two parameters, like this:

```
http://localhost:5985/WebService?op=GetArticle&userName=ADMIN&password=ADMIN
```

One could think: Well, I write two different methods with only the parameters I need, I expose them and we are done. I'd be fine with it, but the client (that's not mine, it's a third-party software) must have ONLY ONE method to call, so if it want to be returned some data, it calls the method with only username and password and if it wants some other data, it calls GetArticle(username, password, brand).

I've read about optional parameters in WCF and it doesn't seem to be any way to call a webmethod without specifying each parameter, nor to have two methods with the same name and different signatures (overloading). I already tried using the `MessageName` attribute inside the `[WebMethod]` tag, like:

```
[WebMethod (MessageName = "GetBrands")]
public void GetArticle(string userName, string password, string brand)
{
   // Do stuff...
}

[WebMethod]
public void GetArticle(string userName, string password)
{
   // Do other stuff...
}
```

But I still have to call those methods using different names. I also tried omitting the parameter I don't want to send, but I get an exception.

Are there any workarounds to achieve this? I know that overloading is a problem related to IIS and not to WCF, but it seems strange to me not having any solution at all...

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia I know that, but this is what has been requested. Actually the web service has an IP filter that only accepts ONE address and the username and passwords are crypted before extract the data from another web-service.

Answer (score 0):

Passing credentials in a HTTP GET query like you described is a terrible idea, it is incredibly insecure and should be avoided.

In any case to do what you want to do, you cannot use optional parameters, `WebMethod` needs a specific signature... Therefore you need to use default parameters instead... ie. `public void GetArticle(string userName, string password, string brand="")`

Comment: I thought about something like this (string.Empty or null parameters by default), but the client should still specify that parameter or else it will get an exception.

Comment: I actually had to move to PHP due to technical limits of the client application that will consume the web service. Thank you anyway for the help.